# How to detect if a DLL is installed/available

Tags: c#, dllimport

What's the most effective way to detect if a DLL is installed in C#?
I'm interessed in this one: msvcr80.dll. I tried to call LoadLibrary interop API call from a C# program, but it didn't work. I just need to detect it, and not make use of it.

Comment: What do you mean with "...is installed in C#" ?

Comment: Why do you need to know? What "real" problem at you trying to solve?

Comment: SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2 depends on it. I want to check if this is met in an installer. Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package would install it, for instance, but many other packages out there do the same. That's why I don't want to put a condition on Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable straight.

Answer (score 4):

Pinvoking msvcr80.dll is difficult.  It is a special DLL, it is stored in the Windows side-by-side cache (c:\windows\winsxs) and there are usually many versions installed on a machine.  I've got 16 of them on this machine.  The side-by-side cache is the equivalent of the GAC for unmanaged DLLs.  Using such a DLL in your code requires a manifest that states what specific version of msvcr80.dll you want to use.

So the first thing you have to do is add the entry to your own program's manifest.  Project + Add New Item, select the Application Manifest item template.  You will have to edit it to include the dependency on msvcr80.dll.  Your manifest ought to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" version="8.0.50727.6195" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Note the version attribute, `8.0.50727.6195` is the latest right now.  Other common revisions out in the wild are 42 (the original RTM version) and 762 (the SP1 version) and a raft of security updates.   You can typically use .42 in your manifest, publisher policy files deployed by the updates will redirect to the latest installed version on the machine.

Also note the `processorArchitecture` attribute, you'll need "amd64" if you want to use the 64-bit version of the DLL.  It is best to stick with x86 and ensure your program runs in 32-bit mode.  Right-click your EXE project, Properties, Build tab, Platform target = x86.

You can now use a [DllImport] to call a function from the DLL.  Like:

```
    [DllImport("msvcr80.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern IntPtr _errno();
```

I intentionally picked an innocent function that doesn't do anything useful.  So that you can pinvoke it to test if the DLL with the required version number is installed.  Catch the exception to know that it isn't there.  If you want to do it without the exception then pinvoke LoadLibrary().

I'm going to guess that you didn't quite count on these complications.  An entirely different approach is to use the equivalent DLL that's used by Windows code.  Which is fine as long as you don't try to pinvoke "unusual" functions.  Every install of Windows has msvcrt.dll, no need to check it for its presence and no need for the manifest.  Just change the DLL name in the [DllImport] attribute.  But do beware that you take the risk that your program might break someday when Microsoft significantly alters this private copy of the CRT.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check both the directories under the `PATH` environment variable, and the *Global Assembly Cache*, which is best done using [this API](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317540).